# Int 10H not working in QEMU

Tags: assembly, x86, qemu, bootloader, bios

I am learning x86 real mode programming, and have written a small bootloader using *QEMU* to test it. I have chosen GNU assembler for learning.

Here is assembly code:

```
#
# boot.s
# 

.section .text
.globl start
start:
//setup stack    
    mov     $0x7c0,     %ax
    mov     %ax,        %ss
    mov     $512,       %sp

    //setup video
    mov     $0x0,       %eax
    mov     $0x0,       %al
    int     $0x10

    //print a character say 'm'
    mov     $'m',      %al
    mov     $0x0E,      %ah
    int     $0x10
1:
    jmp 1b
```

The following text is shown on the *QEMU* display:

> Booting from Hard disk...

**The problem**: The message above is printed, and it remains like that appearing to do nothing.

The script I used to assemble, link is:

```
> to assemble :     gcc -c boot.s
> to link     :     ld -T link.ld boot.o -o b.bin
> to put on bootsector of Hard-disk image
    dd if=b.bin of=HD.img conv=notrunc
> to attach boot magic 
    echo -ne "\x55\xaa" | dd seek=510 bs=1 of=HD.img
> to emulate:        qemu-system-i386 HD.img
```

The linker script copied from an online tutorial I saw somewhere, since I didn't know how to create one myself:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")
ENTRY(start)
phys = 0x00100000;
SECTIONS
{
.text phys : AT(phys) {
    code = .;
    *(.text)
    *(.rodata)
    . = ALIGN(4096);
}
.data : AT(phys + (data - code))
{
    data = .;
    *(.data)
    . = ALIGN(4096);
}
.bss : AT(phys + (bss - code))
{
    bss = .;
    *(.bss)
    . = ALIGN(4096);
}
end = .;
}
```

Do I need to specify any extra arguments or there is some mistake in code? I thought it's the setting up of stack but tried many possibilities but it didn't work.

How do I get past the hard disk booting message and have my bootloader display the letter `m` on the screen?

My working platform is Fedora 23.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? That is not a meaningful problem description.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that your linker script was written for an environment where a protected mode kernel would be loaded at 0x00100000. This is common for bootloaders conforming to the [multiboot specification](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot/multiboot.html#Boot-information-format). Real mode bootloader like yours will be read from the first 512 bytes of the disk and placed at 0x7c00 in memory. You'll need a linker script that uses an origin point of 0x7c00. You can also use the linker script to output the boot disk signature 0xAA55.

A basic bootloader linker script could look something like this `link.ld`:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary");
ENTRY(start);
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x7C00;
    .text : AT(0x7C00) {
        *(.text);
    }
    .data : SUBALIGN(0) {
        *(.data);
        *(.rodata);
    }
    .bss : SUBALIGN(4) {
        __bss_start = .;
        *(COMMON);
        *(.bss)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __bss_end = .;
    }
    __bss_sizel = SIZEOF(.bss)>>2;
    __bss_sizeb = SIZEOF(.bss);

    /* Boot signature */
    .sig : AT(0x7DFE) {
        SHORT(0xaa55);
    }
}
```

Your `boot.s` is not being told to generate 16-bit code. You can place the directive `.code16` at the top of your assembly file to force it to generate 16-bit instructions. You will also have to amend your *GCC* command to compile as 16-bit code, and the linker will need the `-melf_i386` option.

Your bootloader code should really set the *DS* register as well as the stack. Since the linker script assumes code is located at memory location 0x07c00 we'll need to set *DS* to zero. In [segmented model](http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/Segments.html) a physical address = (segment<<4)+offset . *DS* set to 0, and an origin (base offset) of 0x7c00 would map to (0<<4)+0x7c00 = physical address 0x07c00 which is where our bootloader is loaded by the BIOS.

I wrote an answer with some [general bootloader tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32705076/3857942) that may be of some value.

Cleaned up `boot.s` could look like:

```
#
# boot.s
#

.code16
.section .text
.globl start
start:
    //setup stack
    mov     $0x7c0, %ax
    mov     %ax, %ss
    mov     $512, %sp

    xor     %ax, %ax    # AX = 0
    mov     %ax, %ds    # Set DS = 0 since origin point is 0x7c00

    //setup video
    xor     %ax, %ax    # Zero 16-bit AX register (includes AL and AH)
    //mov   $0x0, %ax   # Works but is not preferred for zeroing a reg
    int     $0x10

    //print a character say 'm'
    mov     $'m',      %al
    mov     $0x0E,      %ah
    int     $0x10
1:
    jmp 1b
```

To assemble, link and generate a disk image you could use:

```
gcc -c boot.s -m16
ld -melf_i386 -T link.ld boot.o -o b.bin -nostdlib --nmagic
dd if=b.bin of=HD.img conv=notrunc
```

You could then run it using the image as a floppy:

```
qemu-system-i386 -fda HD.img
```

Or as a hard drive image using:

```
qemu-system-i386 -hda HD.img
```

Comment: That was really working Michael sir, thanks can you please point to some documentations (of ATA, SATA, PCI IDE) by which i can do some vga driver and harddisk drive kinda stuff. I searched a lot on google but everyone gives readymade code. not methods of programming the ports even the osdev.org.

Comment: @Madhusoodan: As for documentation about disk related things, Ralf Brown's intterupt list http://www.ctyme.com/intr/cat-003.htm is a good start . VGA stuff is broad, you should be able to google for that.

Comment: No I don't want to be dependent on the bios anymore and even don't want to copy it from Linux or any other source.

Comment: @Madhusoodan : I suggest then you take a look at [OSDev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org) . They have information about low level disk access without the BIOS.See the section "Storage devices".